# View postscript files on android

Tags: android, postscript

Is there a free way to view postscript files on android?  I cannot find a solution online but surely lots of people must want to do this.

Comment: If you can convert them to PDF, you can use [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/).

Comment: @MuPDF Right. Can you convert to PDF in android?

Answer (score 10):

Recently Sam Buss and I realized that you can upload the PS file to Google Drive and once its uploaded to your drive, the drive viewer will open and render the PS file on your android device.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way that just worked for me on a Samsung Galaxy 5.  Something similar can probably work for others.  The general idea is to download the postscript file, and use an online web service to convert it to PDF, which you can then view.

1. Download the postscript file.
2. Open your browser (I use Chrome).  Navigate to www.ps2pdf.com.  Navigate your way to their "Convert" page, click the "Choose file" botton.  Select "Documents" when it asks for "Choose an action".  Go into your "Downloads" folder on your phone.   Select the downloaded postscript file.  Then, back on the ps2.pdf.com page, click the Convert button.
3. Click the active link for the converted PDF file.  This opened in Adobe Reader, which is my default PDF viewer).    If I want to access the file from other programs, it is in Adobe Reader's "Recent" folder in my phone's documents.